# PostgreSql Select from where date = current Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

how can i select only the records from DB where the Data (Date in portuguese) = the current date

```
SELECT id, data, dia, mes, ano,fornecedor, doc, valor_líquido, total
FROM public.fluxo_pagamentos where data = current_date;
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may suspect that `data` has a time component.  If so, try:

```
where data >= current_date::timestamp and
      data < current_date::timestamp + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= timestamp without time zone
LINE 2:  FROM public.fluxo_pagamentos where data >= current_date::ti...
                                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 111

Comment: @Leogreen . . . Fix your data so dates are stored using an appropriate type.

Comment: This is complex. Use the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

cast to date and use now()

```
SELECT id, data, dia, mes, ano,fornecedor, doc, valor_líquido, total
FROM public.fluxo_pagamentos where data::date = now()::date;
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Simple, straight to the point.